# import win32gui as wn in python 3.9

Tags: python, win32gui, win32-process, python-3.9

I have existing code that works in previous versions of Python using the following module call:
`import win32gui as wn`

I have upgraded to version `3.9`

I get the error message: `win32gui module not found`

The solution to this is to `pip install pywin32`.

I then run the code and it now works. However, i note that when i run the `import` that `win32gui` is not one of the options available in the intelisense, which one might expect if it was available.

Should i therefore be modifying the import to: `from win32 import win32gui as wn` which is picked up by the intelisense in the expected manner or should i leave the old code, which works, but is **not** picked up by the intelisense ?

Furthermore,  why does the code work given the import via the intelisense has **"not seen"** the update suggeted, which i presume should be the correct way of calling the module for version `3.9` ?

Here are the codelines:

```
import win32gui as wn # pip install pywin32 to resolve
#from win32 import win32gui as wn
```

or

```
#import win32gui as wn # pip install pywin32
from win32 import win32gui as wn
```

Answer (score 1):

In your environment, you need to see where is the win32gui. The win32gui in Lib\site-packages\win32\win32gui. So you need to do this:

```
import win32.win32gui as win32gui
```